# enable textbox based on dropdown select do not work

Tags: javascript, html

enable textbox based on dropdown select do not work

***Somehow my textbox is still disabled regardless any selection from the dropdown
can anyone help me on this problem. the code is stated as below.***

```
          <div class ="container">
              <script>
                function changeTextBox()
                {
                         var val=$('#category').val();
                      if(val==='option1' || val==='option2'|| val==='option3' || val==='option4')
                      {
                         $('#subcategory').removeAttr("disabled");              
                      }
                      else{$('#subcategory').prop('disabled', true);}
                }
            </script>

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div    class="form-group">

            <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 control-label" id ="category">Category</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category" onChange="changeTextBox();">
                        <option value="select">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
                        <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
                        <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
                        <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
                    </select>                   
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sub" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sub Category Type</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subcategory" disabled/>                 
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use `.prop('disabled', false)` instead of the `.removeAttr('disabled')`. Then check [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you have set the `id="category"` for both the label *and* the select. Your id has to be unique! Remove the id from the label and all will work well. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj8ced44/) for example. Cheers!